# How to change file associations in Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, file, text, textmate

So I used [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) and all. Now, whenever I open my text files it opens automatically with Xcode. How do I undo this?

Comment: This is more of a superuser question.  Here's a duplicate over there with info:  http://superuser.com/questions/20822/where-does-mac-os-x-store-file-association-information

Comment: Google'ing gives so many answers. This is not a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RightClick on the file name -> Open With -> Choose the editor you wish to open with this kind of file. And that sets to be default editor for opening files with that particular file extension ( i.e., .txt ) when opened in future.

**Edit:** The above procedure is not a permanent one. Try this -

- Right click on the file name.
- Choose Get Info

[image: GetInfo Window]

- Choose one from the **Open With** drop down. This will be set as default application and is used in future if opened the `.txt` file.

Comment: I'm about 99% certain while this method will allow you to choose an application other than the default to open the file, it will not change the default setting for that file type.  Specifically, I open m4v files with QuickTime using this method and the default has never been anything other than iTunes.

Comment: Just confirmed, this method does not change the default file association.  Please edit your question to remove this information or add a working method.

Comment: This does *not* work for some applications (in my case I tried to use an .app I compiled from Applescript). Instead, it reverts to the default app for the file type is you select it using "Change All..."

Answer (score 5):

Right-click any text-file an select "Get-info", then choose your preferred Text-editor under "Open with" and click "Change all..."

Answer (score 1):

You can change program association by right clicking on your file and clicking on "Get Info". This will bring up another dialog in which you can change the program associated with that file type.

You can find visual instructions here: http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/25/change-file-associations-in-mac-os-x/