# I can't execute a .jar file by double-clicking

Tags: java, macos, jar, terminal, executable-jar

I have tried over and over again to get this stupid .jar file, that does nothing but print text, to execute. Do I need a GUI for it? I'm on a mac.

The code is simply...

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("This is a test!");
        System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
    }
}
```

I compiled the test.java file, placed test.class into my Desktop, created a manifest.txt file to make sure that the jar knew test.class was the main file. I wrote

```
Main-Class: test
```

into the manifest.txt file

Then I entered

```
[Macintosh:~] mitchellhowe% cd Desktop
[Macintosh:~/Desktop] mitchellhowe% jar -cvmf manifest.txt Test.jar test.class
```

and the terminal replied with

```
added manifest
adding: test.class(in = 341) (out= 186)(deflated 45%)
```

And the Test.jar file was created ==> [Proof of Test.jar creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCcrr.png)

However when I double-click to execute it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwWUV.png)

How can I fix this? Does it simply need a GUI or am I doing something completely wrong?

> ****PS****
>
> I am relatively new to programming, I was just curious about how to create an executable jar file. So please put any instructions/criticism in a simplistic format and I will try and reply. ALSO, I want it so I can double-click the file to execute, not order something into terminal (I already know how to run from terminal). Thanks for any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224831/how-to-change-file-associations-in-mac-os-x. In your case you will choose to open it with `java -jar`

Comment: You need GUI.. Try this link -- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the nail squarely on the head -- you need a GUI. Try replacing your System.out.println with `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mitch says...", "Hello world!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);` and add `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` along with the other imports.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. The OT is asking why his jar will not execute on OSX. Whether it is a GUI based or console based application is completely beside the point.

Comment: This worked! However, you need to add import javax.swing.*; in order for it to work :)

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus OP seems to disagree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not contain a GUI framework so it cannot open. Check out JavaFX or Swing. I recommend JavaFX due to their new SceneBuilder application, it makes building GUI based applications very easy to learn.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. The OT is asking why his jar will not execute on OSX. Whether it is a GUI based or console based application is completely beside the point.

Comment: "Do I need a GUI for it?" I think the question was fairly clear.